# OneDrive authentication (Microsoft Graph) with token caching

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A command line, .NET application. Authenticates via Microsoft Graph for OneDrive access. It's working except it requires the user to authenticate **every single time** the application is run. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth), the API supports refresh tokens, but I haven't been able to plug them up with the Graph API. Has anyone been able to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain a Refresh Token, you need to use the Authorization Code Grant and request the `offline_access` permission scope. You might find this walkthrough helpful, it covers both the Authorization Code Grant and Refresh Tokens: [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/).